# Is it possible to store a value in a struct through a trait?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and is not syntactically valid Rust 1.0 code. Updated versions of this code produce different errors, but the answers still contain valuable information.

I tried this with and without `Box`, with and without lifetimes:

```
trait TraitToImpl {
    fn do_something(self, val: i32);
}

struct Cont {
    value: i32,
}

impl TraitToImpl for Cont {
    fn do_something(self, val: i32) {
        println!("{}", val);
    }
}

struct StoreTrait<'a> {
    field: Box<TraitToImpl + 'a>,
}

fn main() {
    let cont = Box::new(Cont { value: 12 }) as Box<TraitToImpl>;
    let a = StoreTrait { field: cont };
    a.field.do_something(123);
}
```

All I get is this error:

`` error: cannot convert to a trait object because trait `TraitToImpl` is not object-safe ``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, as the error message says, that the trait `TraitToImpl` is not object safe.  That is, it is *not safe* to use that particular trait through a reference (i.e. `&TraitToImpl` or `Box<TraitToImpl>`.

Specifically, the `do_something` method takes `self` by value.  Consider: how does the compiler *call* this method on a `Cont` that's been placed in a `Box<TraitToImpl>`?  It has to copy the value into an argument of type `Cont` (which is what the `impl` expects), but this call has to work for *any* type of *any size* that might implement `TraitToImpl`!

Practical upshot: if you have a trait which contains by-value `self`, or generics, it cannot be used via a reference.  At the point the call happens, the compiler no longer has enough information to actually generate the necessary code.

Maybe try taking `&self` instead? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This error message wasnt clear for me. And, if i understands correctly, it's impossible to pass by-value through trait.

Answer (score 3):

To understand the source of this error, it may also help to look up the definition of *object-safe* in the [Object Safety RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0255-object-safety.md#motivation):

> We say a method `m` on trait `T` is object-safe if it is legal (in current Rust) to call `x.m(...)` where `x` has type `&T`, i.e., `x` is a trait object. If all methods in `T` are object-safe, then we say `T` is object-safe.

As pointed out by @DK, `x.do_something(...)` is illegal since `TraitToImpl` cannot be passed by value.

Note that object-safety can also be violated by deriving from a non-object-safe trait. E.g.

```
trait TraitToImpl : Clone {
    fn do_something(&self, val: int); // this method is object-safe
}
```

would not be object-safe because `Clone` itself has a non-object-safe method (`fn clone(&self) -> Self`).